# How to access the promise result from the HTML in Vuejs

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, promise

I'm doing a website, in Vuejs, for a university project. 
The scope of the function is to find out if a book is setted as favorite and, then, return the name of the icon so it will set automatically the right icon. 
To do this I created the function `setIcon()`:

```
setIcon: async function (id) {
    var favs = await DataService.getFav();
    var isFav = favs.find((book) => book.id === id);
    if (isFav === undefined) {
       return "favorite_border";
    } 
    else
    {
       return "favorite";
    }
}
```

The function, then, is simply called in the HTML part inside the icon tag.
For debugging reasons, I removed the icon tag and left the button one, so I can see what is the returned value from the function as the name of the Button.

```
 <md-button class="md-button" @click.stop="setFav(book.id)">
       {{ setIcon(book.id) }}
 </md-button>
```

The problem is that the value the function return is a `Promise Object` and not the string `"favorite_border"` or `"favorite"`.

So my question is how can I access the result of the promise in the HTML part?

I tried also to put the `.then()` part after `setIcon()` but the result is the same

Comment: Don't have the template call setIcon() directly, have the component call it on mount, and write the results to state; the template should read the state variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have to use `async`,try this:

```
setIcon: function(id) {
    DataService.getFav().then((favs) = >{
        var isFav = favs.find((book) = >book.id === id);
        if (isFav === undefined) {
            return "favorite_border";
        } else {
            return "favorite";
        }
    })
}
```

if `DataService.getFav()` method has no params and get the same result, you should cache the result in the other method, otherwise each execute `setIcon` will call `DataService.getFav()`,it's the waste of performance.

Comment: Thanks, in the end I solved the problem creating a variable `Favorite[ ]` in data, so I can access it from everywhere, and I fill it in `created: function() {}` so that I have to call it only the first time that the **page** is created and not every time that a **card** is created and then in the function `setIcon()` I put the find function and the condition to set the icon and it works